# Any ideas on why this question didn't get any responses

Tags: support, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

I asked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003169/how-can-i-copy-home-and-to-new-partitions-on-the-same-drive-which-i-can-boot) 17 days ago (although I revised the title later).

I don't expect miracles (although sometimes I get them ;)  ), but I am surprised at getting nothing.

Is there something I can do/could have done to improve the question?

Should I repost this somewhere else such as SE Unix and Linux (and can I do that without getting anybody mad for cross posting)?

Comment: You can crosspost if you delete the question here.

Comment: I will add a bounty to the question for you, it will last a week and perhaps get you an answer.

Comment: Thank you!  I hope it works.